# Complex analysis background for Ordinary Differential Equations.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am an undergraduate with a basic idea of the study of real variables. I have taken a first course in Ordinary Differential Equations with a purely techniques-based approach. I have no idea of complex analysis whatsoever.

I wish to learn Ordinary Differential Equations in a rigorous and complete manner. For the same, I have chosen Coddington and Levinson's *Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations*; for with my likings and needs, this book has the perfect coverage.
The preface of the book mentions the prerequisites to be "**a knowledge  of matrices and the *essentials* of functions of a complex variable.**"

For anyone who has read this book, I wish to ask -- what would be the bare minimum of such **essentials**? Precisely, what topics in Complex Analysis are sufficient for me to begin such a study of ordinary differential equations?

[Any readings on the suggested topic(s) would also be of great help]

Comment: I expect you need to know what $i$ is, how to find the real and imaginary parts of expressions, and especially how to use $e^{i x} = \cos x + i \sin x$. How about just read the book and study when you hit confusing parts ?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra, as it applies to characteristic polynomials and the general solution of some classes of linear DE that are frequently used as exercises. Power series and the relation of the radius of convergence to the singular points of the represented function., mostly for the expansion in (Frobenius) power series and where they are valid. Both is more calculus than function theory.